# MongoDB gps closest to me

Tags: mongodb, geospatial

I have a collection of latitudes and longitudes and a name, and my locations latitude and longitude on a MongoDB 2.2 database. I know how to do the query in mySQL but mongo is still a bit new to me and we've opted to use mongo to store the data

How would I query mongodb to return me a list of results in ascending order of their distance from me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geospatial indexing and query support is in-built in MongoDB. For details, you may refer:
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing

10Gen has a very nice presentation here:
http://www.10gen.com/presentations/mongosf-2011/geospatial-indexing-mongodb